# Scala sum map of list

Tags: scala, dictionary, sum, reduce

I have structure like that :

```
List(
   Model("Name" -> "first"
         "Items" -> Map("a"->1,"b"->2)),
   Model("Name" -> "Second",
         "Items" -> Map("d"->2,"e"->3)))
```

And I am trying to get the sum of items as following:

```
List(
   Model("Name" -> "first"
         "Items" -> 3,
   Model("Name" -> "Second",
          "Items" -> 5)
```

Any idea of how I could do that in a short and good scala way?

thanks

Comment: What does the `Model` class look like?

Comment: It's a salat Model. And to access to my firsts items I can do something like myList(0).items

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with salat - what are valid types for the constructor parameters? They appear to be tuple2s, but with different parametric types in the initial and final values. Does this mean the second param is something like `Tuple2[String, Any]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `Model` is a subtype of `scala.Product`, something like this might do the trick.

```
modelList.map { m =>
  m.copy(
    items = m.items.values.foldLeft(0) { _ + _ }
  )
}
```

Comment: Nice, I wasn't aware of `sum` -- learn something new every day I guess!

Comment: .sum does the same as using foldleft under the hood.